# 100Ω and High-speed data lines

Tags: pic, transistors, high-frequency

I just had a problem with some lines coming from a PIC IO bank, and going into the base of a transistor (BC635) at some high speed.

Without any base protection (since the PIC can't provide enough current to damage the transistors) I start experiencing some synchronization issues, with some not being turned off before the next turn on.

After putting some 100Ω in series, the synchronization issues disappear.

Why?
Should all high-speed data lines have some resistance? If so, how much?

Comment: How are you getting 30 MHz out of a PIC?

Comment: 18F4550.20MHz Crystal - PLL set to provide 96MHz. IO banks can run at max ~40MHz

Comment: They won't! Check the data sheet.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Fig2.1 suggests that the max the CPU and peripherals can run at is 96/2 -> 48MHz. But Table 28.11, suggests that it can the output change time is max of 25nS -> 40MHz. What have I missed?

Comment: The 40 MHz CPU clock has to be divided by four, giving 10 MIPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transistor with excess base current will be driven very hard into saturation. Because of this, the transistor will become very slow because it takes some time for the transistor to come out of saturation. A small signal transistor like an BC807 can switch 15V in a few nano seconds if you avoid saturation. (A Baker clamp might help.)

You should also try to avoid stressing the PIC by driving a transistor without a base resistor. The DIE of the PIC might become hot and fail early. The PIC not being able to supply enough base current to damage the transistor doesn't mean you should clamp it 0.7V above GND. Doing so might also trigger other effects on the IO pin. (I'm thinking about cross-conduction somewhere in the back of my mind. But the full picture doesn't show up.)

You might be better of using small signal MOSFETS instead of transistors.

Regards

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can also use a larger base resistor and add a small (say 220pF) capcitor across the resistor. It's called a speed-up capacitor. At turn on, the capcitor will short out the resistor for a very short time. At turn of, it will reverse bias the base - emitter junction for a very short time, speeding up the removal minority carriers from the base.

Answer (score 2):

The BC635 is nowhere near fast enough for that application. Something with an ft of at least 300 MHz would be better.

You are probably getting reflections on the signals, the 100R resistors damp them. Microstrip lines would be better than ordinary PCB tracks.